# WSGI Script Cannot Be Loaded as Python Module - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: django

I have a project that is working in a virtual machine, but I am having issues getting it running on the production server.  Here is a snippet from my log that seems to capture the errors.

```
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.382574 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276] mod_wsgi (pid=6160): Target WSGI script '/var/www/smarthome/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.382814 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276] mod_wsgi (pid=6160): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/smarthome/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.382975 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.383133 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]   File "/var/www/smarthome/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.383365 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.383479 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.383662 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]     django.setup()
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.383763 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.383928 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.384027 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.384195 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sun Dec 06 15:15:17.384342 2015] [:error] [pid 6160:tid 1969222704] [client 192.168.0.188:58276] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Here is my apache2.conf:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

Listen 8000
ServerName 192.168.0.204:8000

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here's my 000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName 192.168.0.204:8000

    ServerAdmin <redacted>@hotmail.com

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static/ /var/www/smarthome/static/
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/smarthome/static/icons/favicon.ico

    #allow access to static files
    <Directory /var/www/smarthome/static>
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #allow access to wsgi file
    <Directory /var/www/smarthome>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ServerSignature Off

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/smarthome/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/smarthome/
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here's my wsgi.py file:

```
"""
WSGI config for smarthome project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: It's saying that in your `settings.py` file, you are calling `import smarthome.rest_framework_config` (line 104), but there is no file under your app directory `smarthome/rest_framework_config`. Make sure that file exists

Comment: I resolved that part of the error, since the wsgi.py is in application folder, I did not need the "smarthome." prior to rest_framework_config.  There were a couple of other places in the same file with that error.  I updated the error log to the current state.